# Legitimacy of a solution

Tags: real-analysis, limits

- Problem

$$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2}{n^2})...(1+\frac{n}{n^2})$$

Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$

- My solution

We have $$\ln(a_n)=\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})+\ln(1+\frac{2}{n^2})+...\ln(1+\frac{n}{n^2})=$$ $$=\frac{1}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2})+\frac{2}{n^2}+o(\frac{2}{n^2})+...+\frac{n}{n^2}+o(\frac{n}{n^2})$$ $$=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}+no(\frac{1}{n})$$

Taking the limit when $n\rightarrow\infty$ we get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}ln(a_n)=\frac{1}{2}$$ or $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\sqrt{e}$

- My question: I'm pretty sure that my result is right, but I don't know if my proof is rigorous, especially in the part I take:
  $$o(\frac{1}{n^2})+o(\frac{2}{n^2})+...+o(\frac{n}{n^2})=no(\frac{1}{n})$$

It seems true, but is it rigorous?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by rigorous (I would say not). If you want to formalize the argument a little more, you can use the Taylor estimates for the error of the linearization of $\ln(1 + x)$, and you should have more than enough control to guarantee convergence using the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: So where is the wrong part in my argument. It seems legit to sum $n$ infinitesimal quantity. ($o(x)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is : $$\sum_{k=1}^n o(\frac{k}{n^2} )= o(1)$$
The proof is simple, for $n$ large enough (depending on $\epsilon>0$) we have $\left|o\left(\frac{k}{n^2} \right)\right|<\frac{\epsilon }{n}$, sum to get : $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n o(\frac{k}{n^2} )\right|\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \left|o(\frac{k}{n^2} )\right| \leq \epsilon$$
This finishes the proof. For an alternate solution you could use :$$ \forall x> 0 \ : \ x>\ln(1+x)>x-\frac{x^2}{2}.$$
This way you get rid of all $o$ and $\epsilon$ headaches.

Comment: You choose $n$ according to each $k$ and $\varepsilon$, which is in turn depends on $n$ because $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$. Is it somewhat not rigorous?

Comment: for any $\epsilon>0$,for $n$ large enough, we have $|o(k/n^2)|<\epsilon k/n^2<1/n$.
This holds since $o(x)/x<\epsilon $ for $x$ near zero.

Comment: But the range $x$ near zero depends on the function $o(x)$.

Comment: Yes, and $\epsilon$ too. Where is the problem ?

Comment: There are $n$ function $o(x)$ here, then if you want to choose a specific $\delta$ such that with $|x|<\delta$, all $o(x)<\epsilon$, you must fix $n$. Then you couldn't make $n$ large enough.

Comment: for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an appropriate $\delta$, that's all what we need. This means that we can make $n$ large enough, we do not fix $n$.

Comment: For ONE specific function $o(x)$, with any $\varepsilon$ there is an appropriate $\delta$. Therefore if you want to choose $\delta$ for the sum of $n$ function $o(x)$, I think you must fix $n$.

Comment: no, the proprety $o(k/n^2)<1/1n$ with $1<k<n$ is valid for an infinity of integers $n$ starting from an enough large number.

Comment: Can you prove that clearly? Thanks! I think for each $o(k/n^2)$ there exist $\delta_\varepsilon (k)$, and then I couldn't prove without fixing $n$

Comment: Note that $0<k/n^2<1/n$ if $1/n<\delta$ we have $k/n^2<\delta$ and the rest follows.

Comment: The $\delta$ must satisfy: if $x<\delta$ then $o(x)<\varepsilon$. You can only do that if $o$ in $o(\frac{k}{n})$ is the same function with every $k$... But it seems like $o(x)=ln(1+x)-x$ is satisfied here, so now I'm quite comfortable with your reasoning. +15 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In the same track as your, let us consider $\log(1+\frac{i}{n^2})$ when $n$ is large. Using one more term, the Taylor expansion is $$\log(1+\frac{i}{n^2})=\frac{i}{n^2}-\frac{i^2}{2 n^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^5\right)$$ Now, sum. For the first portion, we get $$\frac{n+1}{2 n}$$ for the second $$-\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1)}{12 n^3}$$ in which we see that the degree of numerator is $2$ and degree of denominator is $3$. Adding more terms will make the difference of degrees increasing by one unit.  So, the limit of the sum is what you wrote. If we add the two sums, we then find for the sum of the logarithms, $$\frac{(n+1) \left(6 n^2-2 n-1\right)}{12 n^3}$$ the development of which being $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3 n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$$